# How can I make Netlify create a .env file during build? Or how can I make dotenv pick up system variables?

Tags: node.js, webpack, netlify, dotenv

I have the following working okay locally:

```
// .env
MY_ENV='test'
MY_URL='http://192.168.0.16'
```

```js
// webpack config
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.config().parsed)
  })
]
```

But when I try using `MY_ENV` and `MY_URL` with Netlify, they're `undefined`. I already set them up on the "Environments" tab in Netlify's dashboard.

I suspect `dotenv` looks for a `.env` file, but not system variables.

I know the plugin `dotenv-webpack` allows you to use system variables, but `dotenv-webpack` is a no-no since I need those variables to be used in the browser (they're not really secrets).

Is there any way I can make Netlify create a `.env` locally, so `dotenv` can pick it up? Or is there any way I can make `dotenv` use system variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Do run webpack during build or when your application starts? Does webpack ever run in prod? If no, it's basically too late for environment variables to change, they are baked into your build during build-time.

Comment: @Evert it runs both in prod and dev; I saw your comment that you don't need `dotenv` when using Netlify. so Netlify already sets them up, right? but how would I access them in my code?

Comment: I meant that the dotenv package allows you to specify environment variables in files. Dotenv is a hack that replaces regular environment variables, unrelated to netlify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use to access the env variables

```
process.env.MY_ENV
process.env.MY_URL
```

Don't override your process.env

```
const myenv = dotenv.config().parsed;

plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    MY_ENV: myenv.MY_ENV || process.env.MY_ENV,
    MY_URL: myenv.MY_ENV || process.env.MY_ENV,
  })
]
```

Comment: hey! i'm already doing that; the issue is that `dotenv` only picks up the variables inside `.env`. however, there's no `.env` with Netlify since the `.env` doesn't get pushed to Github. i'd like to know if `dotenv` could pick up Netlify's environment variables :/

Comment: @kibe dotenv is a mechanism to make `.env` files feel like regular environment variables. So if you use real environment variables, you don't need dotenv at all. dotenv _is_ the workaround.

Comment: @kibe can you post your sample env file

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar hi yes, it's pretty much the same: 
```REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID=89158e96a0e646f9ad936ad0bf01571e
REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI='http://192.168.0.16:3000/'
```

i just want Netlify to override `REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI` and place the website's URL, instead of my localhost

Comment: @kibe You're deploying the build to Netlify so you should have already set the URL, you'll not run the build process on Netlify.  also you can look into
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack. Read https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/12/10/environment-variables-in-next.js-and-netlify/

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar right, i've tried dotenv-webpack and it didn't work before; turns out that object destructing like `{ MY_ENV } = process.env` doesn't work for some reason. all is good now. thanks!!